# Error :Missing the DataColumn 'LastName' for the SourceColumn 'LastName'

Tags: c#, mysql, console-application

I am updating MYSql databse with a datatable by using query on the datatable. Getting this error continuously even when the columns are preesent both in my csv file and databse. Please someone help out, I have been stuck for a couple of days.

```
            // MySql Connection Object
            ConnectionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NewConnection"].ConnectionString;
            sqlcon = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionStr);
            sqlcon.Open();

            string query = "select * from CUSTOMER ";
            MySqlDataAdapter mySqlData= new MySqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
            MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mySqlData);
            
            Console.WriteLine("Start Execution..........");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the File path (.csv) for fetching LibraryData :");
            Filepath = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filepath))
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(Filepath).ToUpper() == ".CSV")
                {
                    DataTable csvData = ConvertCSVtoDataTable(Filepath);
                    Console.WriteLine("Number of rows in CSV file : " + csvData.Rows.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine("File read successful.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Processing data..........");
                    
                    mySqlData.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
                    mySqlData.Update(csvData);

                    Console.WriteLine("SQL DB Data Updated successfully");
```

Comment: can you show you CSV columns? and please don't write `select *` in code

Comment: My CSV columns are    :   idcustomer FirstName LastName  City Industry